# What do you call the act of moving a variable or constant on the other side of the equal sign?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the act of moving a variable or constant to the other side of the equal sign?

For example:

```
3x = y

x = y/3
```

How do you call the act of moving a constant or a variable to the other side of the equal sign?

Comment: There's no one particular term for this as far as I know. In your example, I'd say "divide both sides by three."  You might say "to solve for x" as well.  Finally,  there's an error in your second equation: it should be "x = y/3".

Comment: and if you meant "3=y/x," it's called a violation of the rule, should x be zero.

Answer (score 2):

General terms are "rearrange" or "manipulate" an equation, or "algebraic manipulation". This is done by performing valid operations on both sides of the equation such that it remains a true statement.
If the purpose of the manipulation is to make one side of the equation into a single variable, that is called "isolating" the variable.